# Why is javascript's Return usefull?

Tags: javascript, return

In many sites, the functions and objects return values. Why is `return` important?

```
Slider.prototype.setCurrent = function( dir ) {

    var pos = this.current;

    pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );
    this.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? this.imgsLen - 1 : pos % this.imgsLen;

    return pos;
}
```

In the example above, why not return `this.current`?

Comment: Because the pos variable is what is being modified.  Returning this.current would return what it was before the function routine was called/entered.

Comment: Because the two are not semantically equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

`this.current` is modified after `pos` is set:

```
this.current = ( pos < 0 ) ? this.imgsLen - 1 : pos % this.imgsLen;
```

`pos` stores the old value of `this.current`, so returning `this.current` instead of `pos` wouldn't yield the same result.

Comment: `pos` is also (possibly) modified after being set by `pos += ( ~~( dir === 'next' ) || -1 );`, so when returned it may be some other value than the old value of `this.current`.